# Fetch rows either with one matching condition or all rows if no matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have a simple table

```
**targeted_url_redirect   targeted_countries        msg_type    non_targeted_url**
http://new.botweet.com    india,nepal,philippines   NEW         http://twisend.com
http://expapers.com       United States,Canada      OLD         http://all.twisend.com
https://tweeasy.com       india,england             OLD         http://all.twisend.com
```

I receive traffics on my website `followerise.com` and I want to redirect users to specific urls based on their countries as defined in the above table. I am able to write query to get rows for the users who coming from the countries that are target stored in my database. But I am looking for a solution to get all the rows if the `targeted_countries` condition not return any rows.

I written below queries.

```
SELECT * FROM tweeasy_website_redirection
WHERE message_type='OLD'
  AND targeted_countries LIKE '%@country%'
```

This query gives me desired rows if visitor coming from the countries `india`,`england`,`United States`,`Canada`

But I want all rows (2nd and 3rd) should be fetched  if a user coming from the countries not specified in `targeted_countries` column.

Also let me know if I need to restructure this table into 2 or more tables to get desired result.

Comment: You should revise the schema and don't store comma delimited lists. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad? "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|190.3718).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `not exists`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tweeasy_website_redirection t
WHERE 
    t.message_type = 'OLD' 
    AND (
        t.targeted_countries LIKE '%@country%'
        OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM tweeasy_website_redirection t1
            WHERE t1.targeted_countries LIKE '%@country%'
        )
    )
```

When it comes to the structure of your table: one design flaw is to store list of values as CSV list. You should have two separate tables: one to store the urls, and the other to store the 1-N relationship between urls and countries. Something like:

```
table "url"
id    targeted_url_redirect     msg_type    non_targeted_url
 1    http://new.botweet.com    NEW         http://twisend.com
 2    http://expapers.com       OLD         http://all.twisend.com
 3    https://tweeasy.com       OLD         http://all.twisend.com

table "url_countries"
url_id    country
1         india
1         nepal
1         philippines
2         united states
2         canada
3         india
3         england
```

Comment: Excellent. Can you also explain meaning of `SELECT 1`

Comment: @prograshid: `EXISTS` just checks if some row exist that satisfy the condition; we don't really need the results, we can discard them with `SELECT 1`. That's just a coding style, `SELECT *` would be equivalent, as for `SELECT NUL` or `SELECT 'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

select * from tweeasy_website_redirection 
where targeted_countries not in (SELECT targeted_countries FROM stack WHERE  targeted_countries LIKE '%@country%')